# Program or Notepad++ function to remove all @ email

Tags: database, email, notepad++

I have large DB with usernames@email and I need only username. I need to remove all @****.com/ru - etc. Can I do it with Notepad++ replace function? I have 1000 types of emails.

Comment: Do you mean "can you use Notepad++ to edit the records in a database?" If so, the answer is "no." But if by "DB" you actually mean "text file" then yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Turn regexp mode on in your search replace dialog. Then use, e.g. the following pattern:

```
@\w+\.com/ru
```

And then simply hit replace to replace each occurance with the empty string.